# how to create a list of events for a list of buttons c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, user-interface

i have a List of Buttons ... but i want to make an events for each button in the list --i have tried this code

```
ButtonName.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Point p = new Point(20 * j, 70);
                Product[j].Location = p;
                Product[j].Width = 200;
                Product[j].Height = 250;
                this.Controls.Add(Product[j]);
            };
```

the event i want to make is that when click on any button it should show a List Box which is related to this button.
and every List box have its own data .... the only problem i want to get a solution for it is to make event for every button in list
is that possible ??

Update

```
for (int j = 0; j < Data.BTN_Name.Count; j++) 
{ 
   Category[j].Click += (sender, args) => 
     { 
        Point p = new Point(20 * j, 70); 
        Product[j].Location = p; 
        Product[j].Width = 200; 
        Product[j].Height = 250; 
        this.Controls.Add(Product[j]); 
      };
```

Comment: Button Name is a list of button not only one button )

Comment: How do the event content differ between each button?

Comment: on click a button should show a list box and every list box have its own data

Comment: `foreach (var button in ButtonList) button.Click += ButtonClickHandler;`?

Comment: What is `Product[j]`?

Comment: @AbanoubMoris - And why are you adding `Product[j]` to the `Controls` collection in the event handler?

Comment: @vasily.sib but how to get the index of clicked Button

Comment: @Enigmativity product[j] is the List if Listboxes

Comment: This is going XY at an extraordinary pace

Comment: @vasily.sib i think if i got the index of clicked button i would be able to solve the problem

Comment: Do you create your buttons dynamically in code?

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < Data.BTN_Name.Count; j++)
            {
          
                Category[j].Click += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Point p = new Point(20 * j, 70);
                    Product[j].Location = p;
                    Product[j].Width = 200;
                    Product[j].Height = 250;
                    this.Controls.Add(Product[j]);
                };

Comment: I'm agree with @TheGeneral, that this looks like "XY problem". Can you tell us why don't you just add a single `Click` handler to each button with designer?

Comment: @ TheGeneral yeah i create it dynamically

Comment: no problem with XY ...... @vasily.sib i can't do a single cause the buttons are dynamically created by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to do this:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < Data.BTN_Name.Count; j++)
        {
            Product[j] = new ListBox()
            {
                Location = new Point(20 * j, 70),
                Width = 200,
                Height = 250,
                Visible = false,
            };
            this.Controls.Add(Product[j]);
            var captured_j = j;
            Category[j].Click += (s, ea) => Product[captured_j].Visible = true;
        }
```

You must capture the `j` variable to use it in the event handler - hence the code `var captured_j = j;` just before the event handler.

Comment: Then you need to improve your question to make it clear what your desired behaviour is. There's nothing about the order of clicking and how that affects the position of the elements.

Comment: this is the solution ..

    var captured_j = j;
thanks

Answer (score -1):

As I can see, you are actualy trying to tie a some button to some listbox. As @TheGeneral said, you can use a `Tag` property of button, but I don't like this approach (although it has the right to be, it is just a matter of habit). Here is my example:

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    private IDictionary<Button, ListBox> _listboxes = new Dictionary<Button, ListBox>();

    // use this if you create a button and listbox simultaneously
    protected void CreateButtonAndList()
    {
        var listbox = new ListBox();
        // initialize listbox as needed
        var button = new Button();
        // initialize button as needed
        button.Click += ButtonClickHandler;
        _listboxes.Add(button, listbox);
    }

    // use this if you create a button for already existing listbox
    protected void CreateButtonFor(ListBox listbox)
    {
        var button = new Button();
        // initialize button as needed
        button.Click += ButtonClickHandler;
        _listboxes.Add(button, listbox);
    }

    private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listbox = _listboxes[sender];
        // do what you want with listbox
    }
}
```

Also note, that you probably doesn't need both `CreateButtonAndList()` and `CreateButtonFor()` methods. You may leave only one that fit your needs.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, I'm not adding a button to a ListBox:\ they (`Buttons` and `ListBoxes`) should be added to `YourForm.Controls` in `// initialize listbox as needed` and `// initialize button as needed` parts of this methods. I just want to point that OP actualy doesn't need an index of button (or listbox) to do something with listboxes on corresponding button clicks.

Comment: @JeremyThompson you should notice `IDictionary<Button, ListBox> _listboxes` there, he is adding a listbox per button and then in click event, he is fetching that listbox which is associated with clicked button.

Comment: Ignore my comment guys